# fetch() is spamming my API with thousands of requests

Tags: javascript, express

I have the following function which gets an image from my API:

```
function fetch() {
    console.log("Fire");
    fetch('https://api.itseternal.net/eternal/stats', {
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://itseternal.net"
        },
        mode: "cors",
    })

    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((api) => {
        document.getElementById('cover').src = api.song.covers.big;
        var string = `background-image: url(` + api.song.covers.big + `);`;
        document.getElementById('body').style = string
    })
    .catch(() => {
        document.getElementById('cover').src = "https://callmehspear.com/cdn/e_black_branding.png";
        document.getElementById('body').style = "background-image: url(https://callmehspear.com/cdn/e_black_branding.png);";
    });
}
```

It did work, but now when I run the function it spams the API as the console gets flooded with "Fire" and my server gets thousands upon thousands of requests.

Comment: Try renaming your `fetch` function to something else like `fetchData`.

Comment: Well, you called your function "fetch" (overwriting the browser's "fetch").  Inside, you place a call to "fetch" (no longer the browser's fetch but yours).  Infinite recursion.  Change the name of your function from fetch to something else?

Comment: _"and my server gets thousands upon thousands of requests"_ - Your server won't see any requests with an overwritten `fetch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named the function `fetch` so it overwrites (or shadows, depending on the scope your function is declared in) the previous value (the function provided by the Fetch API).

When you call `fetch` it logs "Fire" and then recursively calls itself (passing arguments that it ignores).

Don't name your function `fetch`.